# how to replace dict in python?

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

I'm in trouble with memory problem in a hadoop streaming job with python.
In program, I need a struct looks like:

```
dict{"metric_id":set(user_id1,user_id2...),...}
```

In reduce (there are only on reducer), I will calculate how many users for each metric_id. There are about 100,000,000 users now, it consumes about 6G memory.

I have tried module [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) , but it's very slow... Maybe I used it in wrong ways looks like:

```
tmp_set = set()
for id in value.split(","):
    if id != "":
        tmp_set.add(id) 
if self.ids_dict.has_key(metric_id):
    ori_set = self.ids_dict[metric_id]
    self.ids_dict[metric_id] = ori_set.union(tmp_set)
else:
    self.ids_dict[metric_id] = tmp_set
```

Comment: Fix your application...unlikely that you want to stream 100.000.000 user data....for whatever reason...broken by design

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not a good idea.  There's no reason that I can imagine that you would need to have all 100,000,000 users loaded at once.

If you really need access to the number of users by metric id, what you should do is maintain a separate dictionary or table somewhere of that number, *e.g.*:

```py
{'<metric id 1>': 3,
 '<metric id 2>': 5,
 ...
}
```

Since you already have this information stored as is, you could run a program once (that would be very slow) to collect this information, something along the lines of

```
import collections
numbers = collections.defaultdict(int)
for id, users in mydict.iteritems():
    numbers[id] += len(users)
```

And then update that data structure whenever you add/remove items, so that this value is precomputed.  There is no efficient way to regularly determine the length of an ~100,000,000-length object.

Comment: to jdotjdot:
Thank you answering.
In my program, reducer will receive many value pairs like "metric_id,(user_id1,user_id2...)". The key point is that one user_id may be appear in many pairs. For example:
    metric_id1,(user1,user2,user3)
    metric_id1,(user2,user4)
So I have to use a set() to collect all the user_ids for one metric_id,remove the duplicate user_ids, then count them as the final result.
If I precalculate the count of user_ids for each pair, maybe finally I will get 5 for metric_id1 in before example, rather than 4.
Anyway, I will think another better way to do it. Thanks again